# React - PropTypes are checked at creation time not render time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component which can accept children component and decide whether or not to render them. If it renders them, it also passes along a onClick handler to the children.

```
render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="select">
        { this.state.showDropdown
          ? (
            <div className="select__dropdown">
              {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => React.cloneElement(child, {
                onClick: () => this.onOptionSelected(index),
              }))}
            </div>
          )
          : null }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As it seems, these children component would always require an `onClick` handler to be passed on from the parent, so i have marked it as `isRequired` in the children proptypes.

```
Option.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

The problem is, `onClick` is always added by the parent, so when we write the parent component like this:

```
<Select>
      <Option>One</Option>
      <Option>Two</Option>
      <Option>Three</Option>
</Select>
```

We shouldn't need to specify an onClick on the children. But React warns about it:

```
 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `onClick` is marked as required in `Option`, but its value is `undefined`.
     in Option
```

which is understandable as it seems the `Option` elements are created and propTypes checked even before they are passed on to the `Select` element for rendering.

Is there a way to make it work well, should i make the `onClick` not required , or should i pass in a no-op function whenever i create `Option` element , though i know it would be overridden later by the parent.

Comment: imo. don't pass the options as `children` to `<Select>` but instead as a prop like `<Select options={[ 'One', 'Two', 'Three' ]} />` and let the `<Select>` generate the `<Option>` nodes.

Comment: Yeah, that's the kind of API i am trying to avoid, I am trying to keep it as close to the original HTML select implementation